# How to add a hook to the Vertx Launcher

Tags: vert.x

I would like to collect metrics with Vert.x Micrometer Metrics, so I need to set proper options to VertxOptions. I run Vertx with Launcher and there is a hook beforeDeployingVerticle but when I override it it's not called.

I overriden Launcher class and beforeDeployingVerticle method but this method is never executed.

```
public class LauncherTest {

    public static class SimpleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
        @Override
        public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("verticle started");
        }
    }

    public static class LauncherWithHook extends Launcher {
        @Override
        public void beforeDeployingVerticle(DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions) {
            System.out.println("before deploying");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LauncherWithHook().execute("run", SimpleVerticle.class.getName());
    }
}
```

In a result I receive just `verticle started`, but I expect also to have `before deploying` there. Should I add this hook somehow different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] argz = {"run", "your.namepace.LauncherTest$SimpleVerticle"};
    LauncherWithHook launcher = new LauncherWithHook();
    launcher.dispatch(argz);
}
```

Comment: I believe you're right. Also, since 3.6, you can [set all Vert.x options in an external file](https://vertx.io/blog/eclipse-vert-x-3-6-0-released/#externalized-configuration-of-vert-x-options).